# How to work with KivyMD Checkboxes in Python

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I made `MDDialog` with `checkboxes`. When player checks the specific "score limit" I want to callback specific `alertdialog(MDDialog)`. Game is made with `python 3.9.6` `kivymd 0.104.2`. There's no problem. I just don't know how to do it. Here's my `python` code:

```
kv = '''
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory
<ItemConfirm>
    divider: None
    CheckboxLeftWidget:
        id: check
        score: root.text  # makes the score text available from the Checkbox
        group: "check"
        on_active: app.check_active(self.group)  # update app.active

<ConfirmButton@MDFlatButton>:
    text: 'CONFIRM'
    disabled: not app.active  #  disabled when app.active is False
    on_release: app.score_limit()

<ConfirmDialog>:
    title: "Score Limit"
    bg_color: (5, 0, 0)
    type: "confirmation"
    auto_dismiss: False
    items:
        [Factory.ItemConfirm(text="30"),
        Factory.ItemConfirm(text="40"),
        Factory.ItemConfirm(text="50")]
    buttons: [ Factory.ConfirmButton() ]
'''

class ItemConfirm(OneLineAvatarIconListItem):
    pass


class ConfirmDialog(MDDialog):
    pass

class Begindup(MDFloatLayout):
    aa = 0

    def close_winner(self, *args):
        self.victory.dismiss()

    def __int__(self, numb):
        self.aa = numb

    def screen2(self, screenId):
        if self.pressed:
            self.ids.screenId.md_bg_color = 0, 0, 0, 1
            self.pressed = not self.pressed
        else:
            self.ids.screenId.md_bg_color = 1, 1, 1, 1
            self.pressed = not self.pressed

    def update_turn2(self, teamtwo_turn):
        self.ids.teamtwo_turn.text = (f"{teamtwo_turn}'s Turn")

    def update_score(self, score_one, *args):
        self.ids.score_one.text = score_one
        winner = int(self.ids.score_one.text)
        if (winner >= 30 and winner <= 39 and self.aa == 0):
            self.aa = 1
            show_winner(self)

        if (winner >= 40 and winner <= 49 and self.aa == 0):
            self.aa = 1
            show_winnerdup(self)

        if (winner >= 50 and winner <= 59 and self.aa == 0):
            self.aa = 1
            show_winnerdupdup(self)

        if (winner >= 60 and winner <= 80 and self.aa == 0):
            self.aa = 1
            show_winnerf(self)

class MyApp(MDApp):
    active = BooleanProperty(False)  # keeps track if any Checkbox is active

    def show_confirmation_dialog(self, *args):
        self.dialog = ConfirmDialog()
        self.dialog.open()

    def score_limit(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.dialog.dismiss()
        self.dialog = None  # required to eliminate current group of Checkboxes
        self.active = False

    def check_active(self, group):  # update app.active and return current score limit (or None)
        for cb in MDCheckbox.get_widgets(group):
            if cb.active:
                self.active = True
                return cb.score
        self.active = False
        return None

    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string(kv)
```

Answer (score 0):

Good day. You could create the function `alertDialog` as an app method.

If you are having issues with accessing widgets, use [ids](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#accessing-widgets-defined-inside-kv-lang-in-your-python-code).